# emails not going as spamhaus has us on their blacklist

Tags: email

since last 2 days most of our mails are being rejected as we are being blacklisted by spamhaus.
Now the ip is blacklisted but the website itself shows clean. ( and spamhaus report says EiTest infection )
so our security agency says website is clean server is infected and they are unable to remove this malware.
and hosting company says they cannot find any malware on the server and that the site is infected and because the agency has ftp access and not ssh access then it means that they cannot be 100% sure that the server is infected.
we need to fix this issue because we are losing tons of business due to this email issue.
so if you can help us in determining who is the culprit so that we can change that provider and move on and be able to send emails again.
Thank you for your time and any help on this matter will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What are you asking exactly?

Comment: @Nomad to the hosting company we are asking them to clean the malware as the server is infected but they say that there is nothing that they can do as the server is clean and the site is infected and they want us to show them proof that the site is clean.

Comment: Then you should hire another IT company to get a second opinion?

Comment: @Nomad yeah we will get someone else look at our case and see.. but if not i am thinking of moving the server first before hiring another security company to clean our site

Comment: If you’re still infected while moving servers you will likely just get the new server blacklisted as well.